# iOS 11 UINavigationBar category issue

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios11, objective-c-category

When I override layoutSubviews of UINavigationbar, all the subviews are getting removed. I am trying to set custom Navigationbar height. It was working fine, but breaking in iOS 11. It is a custom category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a subclass of UINavigationBar with setFrame: and layoutSubviews methods. You need to set the subclass as NavigationController's NavigationBar in Storyboard.

```
CGFloat const NavBarHeight = 88.0;

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    return [self getNavBarSize];
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.size.height = NavBarHeight;

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class])  containsString:@"UINavigationBarContentView"]) {
            subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.frame.size.width, NavBarHeight-30);
        }
        [subview sizeToFit];
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];

}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) containsString:@"BarBackground"]) {
            subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, self.frame.size.width, NavBarHeight+20);
            [subview sizeToFit];
        }else if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class])  containsString:@"UINavigationBarContentView"]) {
            subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.frame.size.width, NavBarHeight-30);
        }
    }
}
```